# Oxyplot BarSeries format function

Tags: oxyplot

I need to format the label inside the BarItem so it can have a time format, like 00:10. 
I'm using the BarSeries.Format function, but if I don't use the BarSeries.LabelFormatString the labels don't show and if I use  LabelFormatString all labels will have the same format/values.

Here's my code:

```
BarItem baritem = new BarItem {Value = 10};  //in seconds
Object[] time = new object[2];
time [0] = "00";
time [1] = "10";
barSeries.Format("{0}:{1}",baritem,time);
```

With this code it shows no labels. Using `barSeries.LabelFormatString = "{0}"` shows 10.

I've tried `barSeries.LabelFormatString = barSeries.Format("{0}:{1}",baritem,time)` but then all labels became the same...

Answer (score 0):

For someone that had the same problem, the solution is simple, just subclass the BarItem Class, like this:

```
class TimeBarItem : BarItem {
  public TimeSpan Time { get { return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.Value); } }
}
```

After that we can do:
`barSeries.LabelFormatString = "{Time}"`